# yAxis control for stacked bar chart

Tags: chart.js

I have been looking online and in the source code of Chart.js to find a way to use the stacked bar chart without stacking (summing) the values.

Example:

My data points are 1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4 for the stacked bar.  The chart y axis by default will sum that up to 12.5 (standard stacked bar behaviour).

What I would like is that each stack only go to its literal value, not the summed value.

In the example above, I would expect stack 1 to go to 1 on the y, 2 to 2 and so on until 4.

Is this possible OTB? Or will I need to write a custom chart renderer to achieve the desired result.

Note: The sequences will always be in order, and never have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  I had set stacked on both x and y axes where all I needed to do was stack on the x axes.